# Infer row type from table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic

My application uses multiple schemas to partition tenants across the database to improve performance. I am trying to create a plpgsql function that will give me an arbitrary result set based on the union of all application schemas given a table. Here is what I have so far (inspired by [this blog post](https://clarkdave.net/2015/06/aggregate-queries-across-postgresql-schemas/)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_union(tbl text) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
  schema RECORD;
  sql TEXT := '';
BEGIN
  FOR schema IN EXECUTE 'SELECT distinct schema FROM tenants' LOOP
    sql := sql || format('SELECT * FROM %I.%I %s UNION ALL ', schema.schema, tbl);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE left(sql, -11);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This works great, but has to be called with a row type definition at the end:

```
select * from app_union('my_table') t(id uuid, name text, ...);
```

So, **how can I call my function without providing a row type?**

I know that I can introspect my tables using `information_schema.columns`, but I'm not sure how to dynamically generate the type declaration without a lot of case statements (`columns` doesn't report the definition sql the way that e.g., `pg_indexes` does).

Even if I could dynamically generate the row declaration, it seems I would have to append it to my former function call as dynamic sql anyway, which sort of chicken/eggs the problem of returning a result set of an arbitrary type from a function.

Comment: If it is not too late consider to use [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html) or [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) instead. It would be sompler and much more efficient.

Comment: PS: `sql := string_agg(distinct format('select * from %I.%I', schema, tbl), ' union all ') from tenants;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of providing the table as a string, you could provide it as type `anyelement` to specify the actual type of the returning data, then infer the table's name using `pg_typeof`. You can also use `string_agg` rather than a loop to build your sql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_union(tbl anyelement)
RETURNS setof anyelement AS $$
BEGIN
  return query execute string_agg(
    distinct format('select * from %I.%I', schema, pg_typeof(tbl)::text), 
    ' union all '
  ) from tenants;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from app_union(null::my_table);
```

[Simplified example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=18306ad1f37807035bd6afcaf5895755)